# How to mock and test delete service?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

So I am making Spring boot Tests on my Rest API and I am struggling a lot. When I search for tests online and try to replicate them, they do not work. How do I test delete service? Do I need to save new user first or is there another way to test it out?

```
package com.example.tattooweb.user;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThatThrownBy;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserService underTest;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        underTest = new UserService(userRepository);
    }


    @Test
    void shouldDeleteUser() {
//        assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class, () -> userService.deleteUser(123L));
//        assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class, () -> userService.deleteUser(5L));
        final User user = new User(
                10001L,
                "Alex",
                "alex.jamal@gmail.com",
                10,
                LocalDate.of(2012, Month.APRIL, 13));
        // given
        UserCreateDto userCreateDto = new UserCreateDto(
                "Alex",
                "alex.jamal@gmail.com",
                LocalDate.of(2012, Month.APRIL, 13)
        );
        underTest.addNewUser(userCreateDto);
        final long id = 223;
        // when
        underTest.deleteUserById(id);
        //then
        verify(userRepository).deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

I made this method boolean while testing, thought it might make it easier. If making API do we want to return status when using Delete endpoint or do we keep it as void method and return nothing?

```
public boolean deleteUserById(Long userId) {
    if(!userRepository.existsById(userId)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("User with id " + userId + " doesn't exist");
    }
    userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    return true;
}
```

If any information is necessary or missing please ask. I'm doing this project for self learning, but been stuck on this issue of mine for past 3 days, I'm new to testing and so far it wasn't very easy.

I also have two questions on top of that.

1. What service methods better kept as void?
2. How often do you write tests when it comes to job?

Answer (score 0):

Writing tests could be boring, but as you get stuck in errors, you will find it very necessary to write tests to avoid repeated actions.
Methods like delete and update usually should be void, and you should only look for exceptions and response status.

You can use simply test your repository using the code below:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import({ObjectMapper.class, <yourController>.class})
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
class <YourClassName> {
    // use this to perform api requests
    @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
    // for live testing no mocking
    @Autowired
    private <YourRepository> repo;

    // saved user id
    private static int savedUserId;
    // you are mocking the repository and testing the service layer
    // this is not applicable here, use the above code to test in integration mode.
    /*@Mock
    private <YourRepository> mockedRepo;*/
    
    // optionally used to create json objects
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        
    }


  // save a user with and put the id in static filed (savedUserId)
    @Test
      @Order(1)
    public void saveStaffTest() throws Exception {
      final String link = "/user/save"; // link to your controller api end point
      User user = new User(10001L, "Alex", "alex.jamal@gmail.com", 10, LocalDate.of(2012, Month.APRIL, 13)); // define your default object here
      /***
       *  note: in your User class you might have id as auto generated, because of this you need two constructor one with id, and other without id
       * , or you will have an error.
       *  you can use objectmapper if you run to an error and just pass the object as json string.
      */
      
      // here you are performing save request and getting the result
      MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post(link)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(user))) // this will make the object a json string
                        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated()) // here is what important! it will check the response status, if created 201 the test will success, else it will fail
                        .andReturn(); // returning the result
                String response = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
                System.out.println("from response: "+response); // this is the response you passed on your controller method
                /**
        * knowing your response structure search for the user id
        */
                JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(response); 
                JsonNode id = root.get("id"); 
                savedUserId = id.asInt(); here you save the id in static field savedUserId, then you can pass this id on the next test (delete/update);
        
                System.out.println("id is: "+id);
    }
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void shouldDeleteUser() throws IllegalStateException, Exception{
    // here delete the object, and assert the response state is ok, no need to return any value
    final String link = "/user/delete/"+savedUserId;
                this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post(link)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()); // fail if the response is not 200, couldn't delete the object
        underTest.addNewUser(userCreateDto);
        final long id = 223;
        // when
        underTest.deleteUserById(id);
        //then
        verify(userRepository).deleteById(id);
    }
    
    /***************** save user method to add to controller ***************/
      @PostMapping("/user/save")
      private ResponseEntity<User> addNewUser(@RequestBody User user){
          try {
               userRepo.save(user); // can call the service if you want also
               return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(user);
          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
          }
        
          return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
      }
      
      /***************** delete user method to add to controller ***************/
      @PostMapping("/user/delete/{userId});
      private ResponseEntity deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId) int userId){
          try {
              // you can add the logic to check if user exists first
              User user = userRepo.getById(userId);
              if(user != null){
              // delete the user if it exists
               userRepo.delete(user); // delete
               return ResponseEntity.OK(); // you can add a body response if you want to
          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
          }
        
          return ResponseEntity.badRequest();
      }

}
```